# Play framework 2.3.8, org.apache.poi dependency not found

Tags: maven, playframework, sbt, ivy, playframework-2.3

I added the `org.apache.poi` to my dependencies, but it just does not resolve.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  "net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports" % "6.0.3", 
  "net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports-fonts" % "6.0.0", 
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.1",
  "org.apache.poi" %% "poi" % "3.13", 
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

Getting error, that it does search it but is not found. Interesting is this :

```
Warning:Play 2 Compiler:  ==== public: tried
Warning:Play 2 Compiler:  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi_2.11/3.13/poi_2.11-3.13.pom
Error:Play 2 Compiler: 
 (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.poi#poi_2.11;3.13: not found
```

But in reality, the location of the pom file is here:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/3.13/poi-3.13.pom

**Why does play framework append that 2.11 version there?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove one percentage symbol

```
"org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.13",
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, and here is the explanation why.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461453/build-scala-and-symbols-meaning