# Unable to find the correct SBT dependency

Tags: scala, finagle, finch, twitter-finagle

Today is my first day with Finch.
I am unable to find the right set of SBT dependencies for finch and finagle.

I have tried all the dependencies as shown in Image 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: does it compile from sbt? `$ sbt compile`

Comment: No it doesnt Because I am unable to find the Classes and methods in the Jars.

Comment: Did the reply below answered your question?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks Marios

Comment: Glad to help! It will be good if you click on the tick next to the answer to accept it. It make it easy for others to see that this answer was helpful. It also give you and me some more points :).

Comment: Please, note that the code from a screenshot looks like some ancient version of Finch (presumably, 0.2.0) while you're trying to depend on > 0.10.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Scala 2.12 but your dependencies are for Scala 2.11.

This is the correct way to write what you need:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-core" % "0.13.0"
```

[Build.scala, % and %% symbols meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461453/build-scala-and-symbols-meaning)