# How can I load web3j library to an sbt project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.3, web3-java

I want to load web3j to an sbt project running in Intellj IDE and based on play framework. I tried to add

```
libraryDependencies += "org.web3j" % "web3j-maven-plugin" % "0.1.2"
```

in `build.sbt` but I got errors. Any ideas?

```
Error while importing sbt project:

[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\christos\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\christos\cryptolotto\project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to cryptolotto (in build file:/C:/Users/christos/cryptolotto/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-b84ab1850f860119aa36
[cryptolotto] $
[info] Defining Global / sbtStructureOptions, Global / sbtStructureOutputFile, shellPrompt
[info] The new values will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to cryptolotto (in build file:/C:/Users/christos/cryptolotto/)
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from C:/Users/christos/.IdeaIC2017.3/config/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-structure-1.0.jar
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to cryptolotto (in build file:/C:/Users/christos/cryptolotto/)
[info] Updating ...
[warn]  module not found: org.ethereum#solcJ-all;0.4.8
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\christos\.ivy2\local\org.ethereum\solcJ-all\0.4.8\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ethereum/solcJ-all/0.4.8/solcJ-all-0.4.8.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\christos\.sbt\preloaded\org.ethereum\solcJ-all\0.4.8\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/christos/.sbt/preloaded/org/ethereum/solcJ-all/0.4.8/solcJ-all-0.4.8.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.ethereum#solcJ-all;0.4.8: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
```

Comment: You probably need to include the errors for someone to understand what the problem is (I'm not familiar enough with sbt and play to really help).

Comment: You're missing the repository. Check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ethereum/solcJ-all/0.5.7, there is a note stating that it's located at "https://dl.bintray.com/ethereum/maven/"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please update the question with the specific error you're getting.

What the issue could be is the usage of "%%" between the group id and artifactId. It only makes sense for scala dependencies [to append the version of scala of your project to the artifact id of the dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461453/build-scala-and-symbols-meaning). Since web3j is written in Java, not scala, it doesn't make sense here. Try with the single "%".

EDIT: thanks for updating the question. Indeed sbt is looking for an artifact called web3j-maven-plugin_2.12, because it appended the scala version of your project to the artifact id.

Comment: I tried to use a single '%' but I took the same error :(

Comment: When you do "org.web3j" % "web3j-maven-plugin" % "0.1.2" it should not be saying "org.web3j#web3j-maven-plugin_2.12;0.1.2: not found" any more because it won't add _2.12 to web3j-maven-plugin. Are you sure the error is exactly the same?

Comment: You are right my friend the error has changed! 

 
UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES
 org.ethereum#solcJ-all;0.4.8: not found

Answer (score 0):

I didn't post the error because I thought that adding

```
libraryDependencies += "org.web3j" %% "web3j-maven-plugin" % "0.1.2"
```

was totally wrong way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to solve the it and add web3j to build.sbt by adding the line:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.web3j" % "core" % "3.3.1"
```